# Sum two rows with numeric values

Tags: r, tidyverse, row

In this picture, I want to add the values of the two "Rural municipality" to make them one. I don't seem to know how to do this.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jk29.png)

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: `df %>% summarize(list(location), across(bite_victim_hh:tot_sur, ~ sum(.x)), .by = loc_lvl)` is a start.

Comment: Obviously you cannot sum the *location* values, so you must treat this column differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible with base R. One possible approach is to set the discriminating string of rows to be added to the same value and aggregate by this string.

Example with a builtin dataset:

```
> s <- apply(Titanic, c("Class","Survived"), sum)
> x <- data.frame(Class=rownames(s), No=s[,"No"], Yes=s[,"Yes"])
> x$Class <- as.character(x$Class)
> x
     Class  No Yes
1st    1st 122 203
2nd    2nd 167 118
3rd    3rd 528 178
Crew  Crew 673 212
```

To combine (sum) the two rows of 1st and 2nd class, we first assign them a new identical *Class* name, and then aggregate by *Class*:

```
> x[x$Class %in% c("1st","2nd"), "Class"] <- "upper"
> aggregate(. ~ Class, data=x, FUN=sum)
  Class  No Yes
1   3rd 528 178
2  Crew 673 212
3 upper 289 321
```